# Why cant I answer or comment on a question/answer without being "approved" by someone whom YOU deem fit?

Tags: discussion

For instance.....The question where does the saying "The bees knees" come from was posed on this site. The answers were senseless dribble at best. The correct answer.

Ever wondered why we say this most odd expression: the bee’s knees?

It all started with another expression, still used today.

The expression ‘the be-all and [the] end-all’, meaning chiefly ‘the central or most important element’ is (like ‘one fell swoop’) a quotation from Macbeth. Macbeth is contemplating killing Duncan: “..that but this blow/Might be the be-all and the end-all…/..We’d jump [ie risk] the life to come.” (Macbeth, I.vii.4ff)

This passage is a well-known one, and the phrase the be-all and [the] end-all has been popular over the years. It is usually found without the second ‘the’.

Though many people are aware that it is a Shakespearean allusion, it is not as common as, say, ‘to be or not to be’ and it is usually used without any special reference to Shakespeare.

After years of use, ‘the be-all and [the] end-all’ became shortened to: the Bs and Es (the be-all and end-all), the Bs being the things which are all and the Es being those things which end all.

As this was said, over time (if you repeat this fast, you will see), it sounds like ‘the bee’s knees’.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Dirk Moby.  I suggest you take the site tour and visit the help center for an overview of how this site operates.  There is something called "reputation" (points you get by participating) and your present reputation is only "1", which allows you to ask questions.  As you get more reputation, you'll earn several privileges.

Comment: see http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: Most of us have umbrellas for the senseless dribble; it's worse in the winter.

Comment: @Centaurus but the user can also *answer* questions. I don't get it. Is the question "protected"? Can you provide a link, please?

Comment: @Mari-LouA , I have the Details in my answer ,and yes , the original question is protected.

Comment: Voting to migrate to [Meta].

Comment: It's a bit much saying that the two answers posted are senseless "dribble" though.

Comment: To answer the question in your title in more detail: the reason you, as a new user, cannot (or could not; you can now) write an answer to that question is that it has been _protected_, which means you need a bit more reputation to answer it. The reason some questions get protected is usually that some questions attract a lot of very low-quality or spam answers by people who just happen to wander across the site, thinking it’s a simple message board and writing something that is complete hogwash—or indeed by bots. Protecting a question helps against this, though it does also mean that the →

Comment: → occasional new user who actually has something useful to contribute cannot answer the question until (s)he has posted a few good questions or answers to unprotected questions, so that (s)he has the necessary reputation to answer protected questions, too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA , from here [ http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta ] I see that to "participate in meta" , 5 reputation points are required. OP was new here, so he had 1 point. He can not ask in Meta. Now, even though I upvoted this question , somebody else has downvoted, so he has 1+5-2=4 points only. Still no access to Meta. [ I too "vote" to move this to Meta, I can not see a way to do it, maybe I do not have the access yet ]

Comment: @Prem Voting to move a question to Meta requires having access to close-voting, which requires 3,000 rep points.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet , I guess I have a long way to go , having only half the requirement.

Comment: The question is now **UNBLOCKED**; it is no longer "protected". Write your answer.

Comment: I don't know why someone flagged my comment, or why the mods deleted my earlier comment, but for the record, I unprotected the question within minutes of realizing what the problem was. I also posted a comment urging the OP to post his answer. If that comment of mine was offensive or obsolete, so be it. But it looks like the OP knew only *later* that the question was open to all users, when in actual fact, he was notified after 30/40 minutes.

Comment: I've pre-empted this being posted as an answer on ELU, as there is no evidence cited as to the validity of the etymology. A contributor to Wiktionary Talk says that it is an unsubstantiated theory, like the corruption of _business_.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are referring to may be : [Where does the phrase "the bee's knees" originate from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47088/where-does-the-phrase-the-bees-knees-originate-from)

The answer you have provided seems to be from : http://www.future-perfect.co.uk/grammar-tip/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-the-bees-knees/

Well, I will upvote your question, and if somebody else upvotes too, then you will have enough points to update the earlier question with your answer, but do provide the source, which adds weight.

I know what you are feeling because I went through it when I had 1 point. Wish we had a better alternative, but the current system is not too defective.

Unfortunately, by upvoting your question, I will part of those whom are ranting against, as approvers. Ideally this question must be moved to "meta" but I think you may not have access there yet.